# GtkNotebook add-tab button

Tags: user-interface, gtk

Is it possible in Gtk+ to have an add-tab button inline with the tabs in a notebook, ala Opera or Google Chrome? I do know that Opera uses Qt and Chrome uses custom tabs, but is it possible in pure Gtk+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Check out the class BrandedNotebook at [line 1384 of this file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~fireball-medsphere/openvista-cis/mainline/annotate/head%3A/src/OpenVistaCIS/Main.cs#L1384).

Unfortunately Gtk+ doesn't give you a "nice" way to do this, but you should be able to determine the amount of space available, and use it as you wish. In the case of BrandedNotebook, a pixbuf is drawn in the space, and mouse clicks are handled within the coordinates of the pixbuf.

Comment: Thank you very much. Haven't done much with Gdk drawing stuff -- that's pretty nasty but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if it is not possible, there is a simple workaround:

- Create a tab with the title "New Tab" or "+" or whatever
- Detect when the tab is selected and, when such happens, create a new tab. Focus on that new tab so that the "New tab" tab isn't ever selected.